# Is there a way to use a file field without having to upload the file when creating the content?

Tags: entities, commerce, files

I’m using Commerce File module for creating mp3 products. I’ve been unable to create a bulk feeds importer because of having to upload the files. Is there a way to simply add the file name when creating these products? The files would have already been put on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to give it a filename of `public://...` and use that. Just point it to the file you've uploaded.

Comment: aye! of course, thank you! fyi - am using private:// since these are products

Comment: would you happen to know the answer to this question Nick? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186479/how-can-i-set-a-feeds-importer-to-accept-multiple-values-for-a-field